# ANDROID: changing navigation bar from transparent to black color

Tags: android, layout, uinavigationbar

I have this slider which is an overlay view. It appears over the navigationbar when it below the screen.

[normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdfjx.png)

When a chrome browser is opened, it turns navigationbar to black and the rest works fine.

[in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuyGU.png)

I want to achieve this effect permanetly for the navigationbar while the slider is running

The code overlay slider is here

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;

import com.sleepycoat.tapxicon.utils.ScreenUtils;

import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;

import static android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE;
import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN;
import static android.view.WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE;

/**
 * Created by egslava on 24/08/16.
 * Unfortunately, Android system is not supported (or I could find how) managing keyboard in windows
 * (not activities) that are always on top. So we need to manage keyboard manually.
 */
public class TopScreenDrawerLogic {

    private static final String TAG = "TopScreenDrawerLogic";
    final Keyboarder keyboarder;
    //    private final View fakeFocus;
    View visibleView;
    DrawerView drawer;
    ScrollerLogic scroller;
    private final ScreenUtils utils;
    private final WindowManager wm;

    public static final int COMMON_WINDOW_FLAGS =
            FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS | // for fast "resizing". Window can be moved out of screen
                    FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |    // other windows (on the background, that our window is not overlapped) can intercept touch events
                    FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN; // need for right positioning (getting into account status bar)
    // when FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN is set getHeight() will return value - navigation bar height


    public static final int BACKGROUND_WINDOW_FLAGS = COMMON_WINDOW_FLAGS |
            FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM;     // "back" and other hardware buttons will go throw window
    public static final int FOREGROUND_WINDOW_FLAGS = COMMON_WINDOW_FLAGS |
//            FLAG_LOCAL_FOCUS_MODE |
//            FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |      // if we want go clicks throw the window
            FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH;   // need to know when user touched outside of window to "unfocus"
    private final InputMethodManager imm;

    public static WindowManager.LayoutParams createLayout() {
        return new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, TYPE_PHONE, FOREGROUND_WINDOW_FLAGS, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // mrtndat add 9/9
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static WindowManager.LayoutParams createLayout(Context context) {
//        int w
        Point navBarSize = ScreenUtils.getNavigationBarSize(context);
        Point screenSize = ScreenUtils.getRealScreenSize(context);
        int maxHeight = navBarSize != null ? (screenSize.y - navBarSize.y) :
                screenSize.y;
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

//        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
//        params.x = 0;
//        int diff = 0;
//        if (navBarSize != null) {
//            diff = maxHeight - navBarSize.y;
//        }
//        if (navBarSize != null) {
//            params.y = -navBarSize.y+144;
//        }
        return params;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // mrtndat end 9/9
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public TopScreenDrawerLogic(DrawerView drawer, View visibleView) {
        this.visibleView = visibleView;
        this.drawer = drawer;
        scroller = new ScrollerLogic(drawer);
        keyboarder = new Keyboarder(drawer);
        utils = new ScreenUtils(drawer.getContext());
        wm = drawer.windowManager;
        imm = (InputMethodManager) drawer.getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
//        this.fakeFocus = fakeFocus;




    }

    public int minY() {
        return 0;
    }

    public int maxY() {
        int[] location = new int[2];
        visibleView.getLocationInWindow(location);
        int visibleViewTop = location[1];

        ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams margins = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) visibleView.getLayoutParams();
        int visibleViewBottom = visibleViewTop + visibleView.getHeight() + margins.bottomMargin; //just a bit margin;
        return utils.getDisplayHeight() - visibleViewBottom;// - navBarHeight;
    }

    private int minY(int value) {
        return Math.max(value, minY());
    }

    private int maxY(int value) {
        return Math.min(maxY(), value);
    }

    ;

    public int boundY(int y) {
        return maxY(minY(y));
    }

    // difference between nearest correct Y value and given
    public int yCorrection(int y) {
        return y - boundY(y);
    }

    public int shiftDrawer(int dy) {
        return shiftDrawer(dy, false);
    }

    /**
     * shifts drawer and returns new y coordinate
     */
    public int shiftDrawer(int dy, boolean animated) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = drawer.getLayoutParams();
        WindowManager wm = drawer.windowManager;
//        params.y = params.y + dy;

        if (dy > 1500) {
            new Throwable().printStackTrace();
        }
        final int newY = drawer.logic.boundY(params.y + dy);

        if (animated) {
            new TranslateDrawerAnim(drawer, boundY(drawer.getLayoutParams().y + (int) dy)/* target layout height */, 250).execute();
        } else {
            params.y = newY;
            wm.updateViewLayout(drawer, params);
        }
        return params.y;
    }

    public int shiftDrawerByScreenPercent(float dy, boolean animated) {
        return shiftDrawer((int) (utils.getDisplayHeight() / 100.0f * dy), animated);
    }

    public static final int STATE_UNDEFINED = 0;
    public static final int STATE_FOREGROUND = 1;
    public static final int STATE_BACKGROUND = 2;

    public static final int INITIAL_STATE = STATE_FOREGROUND;

    public int state = INITIAL_STATE;

    public void resetState(View focusedView) {
        if (INITIAL_STATE == STATE_BACKGROUND) {
            makeBackground();
        } else if (INITIAL_STATE == STATE_FOREGROUND) {
            makeForeground();
        } else throw new RuntimeException(new InvalidAlgorithmParameterException("Strange state"));
    }

    public void makeBackground() {
        new Throwable().printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "makeBackground()" + ", previous state = " + stateToString(state));
        if (state == STATE_BACKGROUND) return;
        state = STATE_BACKGROUND;

        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawer.getWindowToken(), 0);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = drawer.getLayoutParams();
        WindowManager wm = drawer.windowManager;
        params.softInputMode = SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN;
        params.flags = BACKGROUND_WINDOW_FLAGS;
        wm.updateViewLayout(drawer, params);

//        final View focus = drawer.findFocus();
//        if (focus != null) focus.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(drawer.getWindowToken(), 0, new ResultReceiver(new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
//                    @Override
//                    public boolean handleMessage(Message message) {
//                        fakeFocus.requestFocus();
//                        keyboarder.applyPos();
//                        return true;
//                    }
//                })));
//            }
//        }, 250);

    }

    public String stateToString(int state) {
        switch (state) {
            case STATE_BACKGROUND:
                return "background";
            case STATE_FOREGROUND:
                return "foreground";
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Invalid state");
        }
    }

    public void makeForeground() {
        new Throwable().printStackTrace();

        Log.d(TAG, "makeForeground()" + ", previous state = " + stateToString(state));

        if (state == STATE_FOREGROUND) return;
        state = STATE_FOREGROUND;

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = drawer.getLayoutParams();
        WindowManager wm = drawer.windowManager;
        params.flags = FOREGROUND_WINDOW_FLAGS;
//        params.softInputMode = SOFT_INPUT_STATE_UNCHANGED;
        params.softInputMode = SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN;
//        params.softInputMode = SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE;
        wm.updateViewLayout(drawer, params);

        // request focus on focused element. Why? The reason:
        // 1. when window is in background state it can't be focused.
        // 2. when window is in foreground state some time it focuses last focused element
        // 3. when this happens Android shows keyboard but DOESN'T call onFocusChanged
        // 4. #Keyboarder class can't process this case correctly and move drawer on keyboard level
//        final View focus = drawer.findFocus();
//        if (focus != null)focus.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
//            @Override
//            public void run() {
//                focus.requestFocus();
//            }
//        }, 250);
    }

    public void dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "dispatchTouchEvent() called with: " + "e = [" + e + "]");
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                makeBackground();
                break;
            default:
                makeForeground();
                break;
        }
    }

    public boolean delegateOnTouch(MotionEvent e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "delegateOnTouch() called with: " + "e = [" + e + "]");
        keyboarder.delegateOnTouch(e);
        return scroller.delegateOnTouch(e);
    }

    // need to process keyboard by ourselves
    public void delegateOnInputClick(final View v) {
        keyboarder.delegateOnInputClick(v);
    }

    public void delegateOnInputFocus(final View v, final boolean b) {
        keyboarder.delegateOnInputFocus(v, b);
    }

    public boolean delegateOnInterceptTouch(MotionEvent e) {
        return scroller.delegateOnInterceptTouch(e);
    }

    public void callWhenEnterIsPressed() {

    }

    public void callWhenKeypressed() {      // for backpressing

    }

    public void callWhenKeyboardIsShown() {

    }

    public void delegateOnKeyPreIme(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        keyboarder.delegateOnKeyPreIme(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

I want to achieve this affect of chrome browser by using Transparent activity with the overlay layout but again the slider appear over the the transparent activity.